# MySQL query with and array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create a tag function in my webpage and I'm using an array of tags to query the database.

```
array[tag1, tag2, tag3];
```

The tags are created in a  field

what I'm trying to archive is something like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `Tags` = '$tag1' AND '$tag2' AND '$tag3'";
```

Except with an array, so

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `Tags` = $array[]";
```

Thanks

```
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ComicStripTags WHERE `Tag` = '$tag'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $ID[] = $row['ImageID'];
        print_r ($ID);
    }
```

BTW I want to use $ID[] to use in another query

Comment: What values does the Tags column of you table contain? Can you list an example? Does it have a comma-separated list of tags per row? Or does  each row have only one tag?

Comment: The `AND` clauses in your SQL query probably won't do what you think they do. Could you edit your question to include the structure of the table you're querying, some example values for your array of tags, and the results you'd expect from your table for a few values of those tags?

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I print_r the $tag array it stacks the values Array ( [0] => 18 ) Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 19 )

Comment: Please share the code snippet to help us understand the problem better?

Comment: @DeadLock I'll edit the post

Comment: @Matt.C do the print_r outside the while loop to print all the final values obtained from the query only once.

Comment: @DeadLock Thanks, that cleared it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using implode to convert array to string, and use "IN" operator instead of equal:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `Tags` in (". implode(", ",$array) .")";
```